# Changing id dynamically in jQuery and jqueryUI modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've a common button `Add Entry` and a list of 15 `<li>` items, say `1,2,3 upto 15`. SO, when I click 1, the button is assigned an id `button_1`, similarly for 2, 3, upto 15.

Now I have different modal box for different list items. Upon clicking on that common button `Add Entry`, a modal box is opened respective to the list item that I've selected.

There is a global variable I've set in the javascript as `add_entry_button_id = 1`. Upon selecting any `<li>` item, I update this variable.

And upon clicking the clicking the button I do this.

**Html:**

```
<button id="1_button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right add_entry_button" style="margin-bottom:10px" onclick="add_new_entry_button(add_entry_button_id)">Add New Entry</button>
```

**This is my code for opening the specific modal box**

**JavaScript:**

```
function add_new_entry_button(button_id){
    console.log(button_id)  // shows the current button_id
    $( "#"+button_id+"_button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#"+button_id+"_form" ).dialog( "open" );
        console.log(button_id)  // shows all the button_ids that i've traversed
    });
}
```

The issue that I'm facing now is though my modal boxes get opens, but when I click multiple `<li>` items, and then Add button, a series of all those modal boxes also shows up which I've traversed previously.

For eg:- If I click on `1` and then add button, a modal box for that will be opened.
Next I click `3` and add button, modal box for 3 will get open and then 1's modal box will also get open.

Similarly, if I click `7` and add button, modal box for 7 will get open and then 3's modal box and then 1's modal box will also get open.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.unbind()` to remove the click event from previously pressed add buttons.

But on another note, I would probably not use ID´s this way. It seems like it's just a lot of trouble waiting to happen. `.data()` might be more suitable in your case.

Comment: Like this? `$( "#add_"+button_id+"_button" ).unbind('click').click(function() {
        $( "#"+button_id+"_form" ).dialog( "open" );

    });`

Comment: With this, the modal box does not gets opened.

Comment: Your problem was that previous modal boxes was opened as well? Now you are unbinding the last button. You should unbind all of them: `$(".btn").unbind('click')`, then add `.click` to the last one like you already are.

Comment: If you put everything in http://jsfiddle.net/, it will be easier to identify your problem :)

Comment: I was initially trying to write to jsFiddle, but unfortunately it isn'e getting opened. Dont know why. Anyhow, I tried `function add_new_entry_button(button_id){
    $(".btn").unbind('click')
    $( "#add_"+button_id+"_button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#"+button_id+"_form" ).dialog( "open" );

    });

}` But the none of of the model box is getting opened.

Comment: I guess its because that I'm removng the click event handler from btn and then trying to click it again, which obviously wont let me do because of unbind method.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure without looking at the whole code, but think about it this way: Just because you change the buttons ID, doesn't mean you remove the previously attached `.click()` to that element. You are only adding additional `.click()` events with unique modal boxes each time you run add_new_entry_button(). You see whats going on here? You should probably be able to figure out a solution with that in mind :)

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: Logical enough. So, how can I remove the previously clicked events from the button?

Comment: It might be hard since the buttons with those ID's no longer exist, but their events still do. Sadly, I think the best thing you can do is to not use dynamic ID´s this way and find another solution where you don't modify the ID of the button. That is probably going to cause even more problems in the future, even if you manage to solve this one. :(

Comment: Otherwise, find a way to `.unbind()` the previous button **before** you change it's ID and attach a new `.click()` to it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try something like this

```
function add_new_entry_button(button_id){
    console.log(button_id)  // shows the current button_id
    //unbind all others button
    $(".btn").unbind( "click" );

    $( "#"+button_id+"_button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#"+button_id+"_form" ).dialog( "open" );
        console.log(button_id)  // shows all the button_ids that i've traversed
    });
}
```

NOTE: I would use **`#button`_1** instead of `#1_button`

Comment: No. Button does clicks...The modal box does not geys open for any.